# How to tell LaTeX/Koma-Script about preamble of book?

Tags: indentation, koma-script, scrbook

Example code:

```
\documentclass[paper=a5,titlepage=firstiscover]{scrbook}
\title{Nunc rutrum turpis}
\begin{document}

\maketitle

\cleardoublepage
\thispagestyle{empty}
% preamble:
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod
tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.

\chapter*{Fusce commodo}

\section*{Pellentesque condimentum}

Phasellus lacus. Nunc aliquet, augue nec adipiscing interdum, lacus tellus
malesuada massa, quis varius mi purus non odio.

\end{document}
```

Before the first chapter, there is the [preamble](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preamble), but LaTeX doesn’t seem to
interpret it as that. It indents the first paragraph, just as if there is
a paragraph before:

[image: How LaTeX typesets text after the title]

*How do I tell LaTeX not to indent the first paragraph in the preamble?*

Of course, I could use `\noindent`, but I wonder if there is an alternative
that tells LaTeX / Koma-Script about the semantics.

Comment: Maybe you want `\dedication{}`? I'm not really sure what you mean by a 'preamble' here.

Comment: @cfr No it's not a dedication. The book in question resembles a collection of letters. The person who did the transcription mentions where the letters come from, etc. There is also a second *preamble* page, where there is a short biography of the author of the letters and some more information. Both pages are without a heading.

Comment: I would probably just set it in a `quote` environment or use a `minipage`. These are one-off instances: semantic markup is not especially useful here anyway.

Comment: @cfr `quote` indents by default, and `minipage` requires specifying a width, which should just be the same as that of the current page. That both doesn't make sense to me. In comparison, specifying `\noindent` in front of the first paragraph is the cleaner solution. It's a common task: Pages like this are found in a lot of books that I have here.

Comment: @feklee re »`quote` indents by default« – no, it doesn't: `\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\begin{quote}
  \lipsum[1-2]
\end{quote}
\end{document}`

Comment: You can define an environment `\newenvironment{preamble}{\par\noindent\ignorespaces}{\par}` and use that.

Answer (score 1):

Try the `dictum` command. There you have seven commands to format this preamble how you like. As `dictumwidth` you just use `textwidth`, i.e. `\renewcommand*{\dictumwith}{\textwidth}`, see page 104 in the English manual-.

You glue this together with `\setchapterpreamble`, see page 102 in the KOMAScript manual.

**EDIT**: You may still use the `\dictum`-command as a single command before the first chapter and with your preamble text as argument:

Your MWE will look like:

```
\documentclass[paper=a5,titlepage=firstiscover]{scrbook}

\renewcommand*{\dictumwidth}{\textwidth}
\renewcommand*{\raggeddictum}{}
\renewcommand*{\raggeddictumtext}{}
\setkomafont{dictumtext}{\normalfont}

\title{Nunc rutrum turpis}
\begin{document}

\maketitle

\cleardoublepage
\thispagestyle{empty}
% preamble:
\dictum{%
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod
tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.%
}

\chapter*{Fusce commodo}

\section*{Pellentesque condimentum}

Phasellus lacus. Nunc aliquet, augue nec adipiscing interdum, lacus tellus
malesuada massa, quis varius mi purus non odio.

\end{document}
```

Not the simplest solution, but you did not ask for a simple solution.

Comment: It's not a chaper preamble, though. The preamble is for the entire book.

Comment: You may still use `\dictum`, before the first chapter-command, but then without `\setchapterpreamble`.